# convert string value to map using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dictionary, user-defined-functions

I have a CSV file with one of the fields with a map as mentioned below
"Map(12345 -> 45678, 23465 -> 9876)"

When I am trying to load the csv into dataframe, it is considering it as string.
So, I have written a UDF to convert the string to map as below

```
 val convertToMap = udf((pMap: String) => { 
   val mpp = pMap
   // "Map(12345 -> 45678, 23465 -> 9876)" 
   val stg = mpp.substr(4, mpp.length() -1) val stg1=stg.split(regex=",").toList       
   val mp=stg1.map(_.split(regex=" ").toList) 
   val mp1 = mp.map(mp =>
   (mp(0), mp(2))).toMap 
   } )
```

Now I need help in applying the UDF to the column where it is being taken as string and return the DF with the converted column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, but it looks like your UDF has some mix of scala and python, and the parsing logic needs a little work. There may be a better way to parse a map literal string, but this works with the provided example:

```
val convertToMap = udf { (pMap: String) =>
  val stg = pMap.substring(4, pMap.length() - 1)
  val stg1 = stg.split(",").toList.map(_.trim)
  val mp = stg1.map(_.split(" ").toList) 
  mp.map(mp =>(mp(0), mp(2))).toMap 
}

val df = spark.createDataset(Seq("Map(12345 -> 45678, 23465 -> 9876)")).toDF("strMap")
```

With the corrected UDF, you simply invoke it with a `.select()` or a `.withColumn()`:

```
df.select(convertToMap($"strMap").as("map")).show(false)
```

Which gives:

```
+----------------------------------+
|map                               |
+----------------------------------+
|Map(12345 -> 45678, 23465 -> 9876)|
+----------------------------------+
```

With the schema:

```
root
 |-- map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Comment: Thank you, Travis for the quick response. I see that you have taken the string value directly as a sequence and created a dataset. 
However, in my case, it should be considering each value from that column (say DealMap is my column in the x dataframe) and when I am trying to take as below, it is throwing me error. val df1 = spark.createDataset(Seq(actual_df.select("DealMap"))).toDF("strMap") Please suggest.

Comment: I only have the `createDataset` call to show a working example. Since you already have a dataframe, then skip straight to the `.select()` step: `val df1 = actual_df.select(convertToMap($"DealMap"))`